# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on opening Java project on another computer

Tags: java, netbeans

My Java Program works fine in my computer but
When Opening an this File in Java on another computer,

I keep getting error message -

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                   

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code     -
package net.proteanit.sql does not exist
```

I am Using Java 7 and Netbeans IDE. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly caused by a missing jar file

-Cause: `package net.proteanit.sql` does not exist

> -solution: download / obtain **rs2xml.jar**
> and add to project's classpath library

to add this jar file:

> go to projects> click on [Current Java Project]
>
> go to Libraries
> right click>Add Jar/Folder > then locate jar file

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Very Fast Answer Thanks :)